# Mocking Activity Lifecycle for RxJava in unit test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, rx-java

Currently developing an Android application with the usage of RxJava.

I got the following piece of code:

```
public Observable<Response<DTO>> getDTO(final BaseActivity activity, final long workorderId) {
    return dtoService.getDTO(DTOId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .compose(activity.bindUntilEvent(ActivityEvent.PAUSE))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

(Please don't mind the naming of the objects, just put some random names to reflect what it needs to do.)

I have running unit tests testing related pieces of code. Altough, those pieces dont contain the `.compose()` method.
Now i tried the following:

```
@Mock
private BaseActivity baseActivity;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

and

```
private BaseActivity baseActivity;

@Before
public void setup() {
    baseActivity = Mock(BaseActivity.class);
}
```

Both of those situations give me a null pointer: `lifecycle == null` (Which it is if i debug it).

How do i mock or test this in any other way? (Also i don't fully understand the compose() method. But i cant seem to find any resources related to this code)

(I provided the Android and RxJava schedulers, so that is not the problem)

Thanks!

Comment: have you considered spy on the actual activity? I would also suggest robolectric if you're unit testing activities. unit testing itself isn't designed for that.

Comment: I have done different type of unit testing on this sample project, Hope it would help: http://github.com/mmirhoseini/fyber_mobile_offers

Comment: But i do not want to test my activity. I just want to know if the method returns an observable with an response with the correct DTO. Thats why i want to mock the activity, because it has nothing to do with this. Or maybe i just do not understand the compose() method?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so. Let's start with `.compose` method. What it does - applies some transformer function to your Observable, which you can understand as *"combine custom sequence of observable methods (like `map`, `flatMap`, etc)"*. I.e. you can use it to combine `.subscribeOn` and `.observeOn` methods ([more here](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/)). Since you are using RxLifecycle, you can just go to the source code and see, [what it does](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle/blob/master/rxlifecycle/src/main/java/com/trello/rxlifecycle/RxLifecycle.java).

If you want to use activity's lifecycle in tests, you have to use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/activity-lifecycle/). It'll give you full control of creating activity and managing it's lifecycle. **That'll help with NPE**. You just setup it and write:

```
    ActivityController controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(BaseActivity.class).create().start().resume();
Activity activity = controller.get();

// Not paused yet
activityController.pause();
// Pause happened! Do something!
```

Hope it helps (:

Comment: Clarified a lot more. Thanks! If i understand my code correctly (It was written by someone else), the call will terminate if the activity is paused? Otherwise it will just continue?
But the problem is, i dont actually want to do anything with my activity. Is there a way to mock the method or activity without RoboElectric? I just want to know if i get an observable back with a Response<DTO>.

Comment: On activity paused, yes, it'll emit `onCompleted()` and call will terminate (according to documentation).

Comment: About mocking - you can try using  `Mockito.when(activity.getLifecycle()).thenReturn(ActivityEvent.PAUSE)` or something like this (this is pseudocode and won't work, I just wanted to show approach)